# phpMyAdmin table appearance looks very wide and stretched

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

I know that this sounds like a silly question, but this has been annoying me since I updated phpMyAdmin to the latest version.

This is the problem I'm having:

Wide Table:

[image: Wide Table]

This is what it should look like normally:

Normal Table:

[image: Normal Table]

Is there a way to turn it back to normal? It's very difficult to see the data when the entire table spans the entire screen.

Comment: Looks like normal behavior. If you have access to the phpMyAdmin sources, you can fix it in css.

Answer (score 1):

This was an annoying regression in 5.1.0, but is tracked as bug https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/16604 and the fix will be included when 5.1.1 is released.